# EF6 with MySQL. The given key was not present in the dictionary

Tags: mysql, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I have Asp.Net MVC 5 application using Code First Entity Framework 6 linked to MySQL database.

When I created the database first time, it works fine. But when I make a change to the model then add migration. An error shows after (Update-Database).

This is the error:

```
        PM> Update-Database 
        System.Collections.Generic.KeyNotFoundException: The given key was not present in the dictionary.
           at System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2.get_Item(TKey key)
           at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnectionStringBuilder.<>c.<.cctor>b__2_7(MySqlConnectionStringBuilder msb, MySqlConnectionStringOption sender)
           at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnectionStringBuilder.get_Item(String keyword)
           at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnectionStringBuilder.GetConnectionString(Boolean includePass)
           at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection.get_ConnectionString()
           at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.DbConnectionDispatcher.<GetConnectionString>b__12(DbConnection t, DbConnectionInterceptionContext`1 c)
           at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.InternalDispatcher`1.Dispatch[TTarget, TInterceptionContext, TResult](TTarget target, Func`3 operation, TInterceptionContext interceptionContext, Action`3 executing, Action`3 executed)
           at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.DbConnectionDispatcher.GetConnectionString(DbConnection connection, DbInterceptionContext interceptionContext)
           at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalConnection.GetStoreConnectionString(DbConnection connection)
           at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalConnection.OnConnectionInitialized()
           at System.Data.Entity.Internal.EagerInternalConnection..ctor(DbContext context, DbConnection existingConnection, Boolean connectionOwned)
           at System.Data.Entity.DbContext..ctor(DbConnection existingConnection, Boolean contextOwnsConnection)
           at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.History.HistoryContext..ctor(DbConnection existingConnection, String defaultSchema)
           at MySql.Data.Entity.MySqlHistoryContext..ctor(DbConnection existingConnection, String defaultSchema)
           at code_first_mysql.Migrations.Configuration.<>c.<.ctor>b__0_0(DbConnection conn, String schema) in C:\Users\User\Documents\Tree\New Backend\code first mysql\Migrations\Configuration.cs:line 16
           at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.History.HistoryRepository.CreateContext(DbConnection connection, String schema)
           at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.History.HistoryRepository.<GetUpgradeOperations>d__16.MoveNext()
           at System.Linq.Enumerable.Any[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
           at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.UpdateInternal(String targetMigration)
           at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.<>c__DisplayClassc.<Update>b__b()
           at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Infrastructure.MigratorScriptingDecorator.EnsureDatabaseExists(Action mustSucceedToKeepDatabase)
           at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.Update(String targetMigration)
           at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Infrastructure.MigratorBase.Update(String targetMigration)
           at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Infrastructure.MigratorBase.Update(String targetMigration)
           at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Infrastructure.MigratorScriptingDecorator.ScriptUpdate(String sourceMigration, String targetMigration)
           at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Design.ToolingFacade.ScriptUpdateRunner.Run()
           at System.AppDomain.DoCallBack(CrossAppDomainDelegate callBackDelegate)
           at System.AppDomain.DoCallBack(CrossAppDomainDelegate callBackDelegate)
           at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Design.ToolingFacade.Run(BaseRunner runner)
           at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Design.ToolingFacade.ScriptUpdate(String sourceMigration, String targetMigration, Boolean force)
           at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.UpdateDatabaseCommand.<>c__DisplayClass2.<.ctor>b__0()
           at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.MigrationsDomainCommand.Execute(Action command)
        The given key was not present in the dictionary.
```

These are my MySQL Configuration Classes:

```
internal sealed class Configuration : DbMigrationsConfiguration<ApplicationDbContext>
{
    public Configuration()
    {
        AutomaticMigrationsEnabled = false;
        SetSqlGenerator("MySql.Data.MySqlClient", new MySqlMigrationSqlGenerator());
        SetHistoryContextFactory("MySql.Data.MySqlClient", (conn, schema) => new MySqlHistoryContext(conn, schema));
        CodeGenerator = new MySqlMigrationCodeGenerator();
    }

    protected override void Seed(ApplicationDbContext context)
    {}
}


public class MySqlConfiguration: DbConfiguration
{

    public MySqlConfiguration()
    {
        SetHistoryContext("MySql.Data.MySqlClient", (conn, schema) => new MySqlHistoryContext(conn, schema));
    }

}



public class MySqlHistoryContext : HistoryContext 
{
    public MySqlHistoryContext(DbConnection existingConnection, string defaultSchema) : base(existingConnection, defaultSchema)
    {
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
        modelBuilder.Entity<HistoryRow>().Property(h => h.MigrationId).HasMaxLength(100).IsRequired();
        modelBuilder.Entity<HistoryRow>().Property(h => h.ContextKey).HasMaxLength(200).IsRequired();
    }
}

 public class MySqlInitializer : IDatabaseInitializer<ApplicationDbContext>
{

    public void InitializeDatabase(ApplicationDbContext context)
    {
        if (!context.Database.Exists())
        {
            // if database did not exist before - create it
            context.Database.Create();
        }
        else
        {
            // query to check if MigrationHistory table is present in the database 
            var migrationHistoryTableExists = ((IObjectContextAdapter)context).ObjectContext.ExecuteStoreQuery<int>(
            string.Format(
              "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM information_schema.tables WHERE table_schema = '{0}' AND table_name = '__MigrationHistory'", "mydb"));

            // if MigrationHistory table is not there (which is the case first time we run) - create it
            if (migrationHistoryTableExists.FirstOrDefault() == 0)
            {
                context.Database.Delete();
                context.Database.Create();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: looks like a connection string problem.
do you have your dbContext  in a project different from the startup one?

Comment: I have only one project, also I do have my dbContext in one place. Please help..

Comment: Does the database already created when running migration with Package Manager Console? If it does, probably you have missed some steps for Code First migration related to `__MigrationHistory`.

Comment: I didn't get you, The first init works fine. But others not. I also added migration history

Answer (score 2):

As you see from the first lines of the error,

> MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnectionStringBuilder.<>c.<.cctor>b__2_7(MySqlConnectionStringBuilder
>   msb, MySqlConnectionStringOption sender)
>              at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnectionStringBuilder.get_Item(String
>   keyword)

the error has to do with the `ConnectionString`. The problem is the `ConnectionString` contains keys that can't be read.

Try to clean up the `ConnectionString` so that it has only

1. server
2. user id
3. password
4. database

In my case, the `ConnectionString` had an extra key `integrated security`. When this was removed `Update-Database` started working fine. Depending on your case however, this might and might not be the key that caused the error.

So again my proposed and guaranteed solution, go through `ConnectionString` and simplify it so that it contains only the 4 keys mentioned above.

Answer (score 0):

[Bug 75172](https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=75172)
It is a bug reported in version 6.9.4,but I review it in 6.9.11.

Answer (score 0):

Don't apply the newest mysql tools

1. Close Visual studio 2017
2. Uninstall mysql-for-visualstudio 2.0.5 Then, install mysql-for-visualstudio 1.2.8
3. Uninstall mysql-connector-net-8.0.17 Then, install mysql-connector-net-6.9.10.
   Find the mysql.data.dll, MySql.Data.Entity.EF6.dll in 
   %Program Files (x86)%\MySQL\MySQL Connector Net 6.9.10\Assemblies\v4.5
   Add to reference
4. Open nuget in references, downgrade EntityFramework 6 to EntityFramework 5

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me: Close your visual studio and

1. go to this folder
   C:\Users[youruser]\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\VisualStudio\16.0_befcda98\ServerExplorer
2. And then delete the file DefaultView.SEView
3. Open your visual studio and try again.

Comment: There are millions of ways to get this exception. That doesn't mean they're all related to this question.