# Troubles Accessing Context In ASP.NET Controller

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I'm building a web app using ASP.NET MVC. I also intend to access a remote MySQL database. Would like to keep Entity Framework.

What I am trying to do is access the context within my controller. This worked without an issue using the vanilla database solution. However, now that I am accessing a remote database, it doesn't seem to be working properly. The connection to the database is valid—it actually migrates and seeds properly. But, when I try accessing a member of the context, the app fails.

**Web.config**

```
<connectionStrings>
    <remove name="DBName" />
    <add name="DBName" connectionString="server=1.2.3.4;port=1234;user id=DBAdmin;password=DBPass;database=DBName;integrated security=True" providerName="MySQL.Data.MySqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
<system.data>
    <DbProviderFactories>
        <remove invariant="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" />
        <add name="MySQL Data Provider" invariant="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" description=".Net Framework Data Provider for MySQL" type="MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlClientFactory, MySql.Data, Version=6.9.9, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d" />
    </DbProviderFactories>
</system.data>
<entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="MySql.Data.Entity.MySqlConnectionFactory, MySql.Data.Entity.EF6">
        <parameters>
            <parameter value="v11.0" />
        </parameters>
    </defaultConnectionFactory>
    <providers>
        <provider invariantName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" type="MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlProviderServices, MySql.Data.Entity.EF6, Version=6.9.9, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d" />
        <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
    </providers>
</entityFramework>
```

**Context.cs**

```
[DbConfigurationType (typeof (MySql.Data.Entity.MySqlEFConfiguration))]
public class Context : DbContext {
    public Context () : base ("name=DBName") {
        Database.SetInitializer (new MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion <Context, System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrationsConfiguration <Context>> ());
    }

    public DbSet<Software> Softwares { get; set; }
}
```

**SoftwareController**

```
public class SoftwareController : Controller {
    public ActionResult Index() {
        using (Context context = new Context ()) {
            List<Software> softwares = context.Softwares.ToList ();

            return View (softwares);
        }
    }
}
```

**Error**

> The given key was not present in the dictionary.

**Source Error**

> List softwares = context.Softwares.ToList ();

**Stack Trace**

> [KeyNotFoundException: The given key was not present in the dictionary.]
>      System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2.get_Item(TKey key) +12769097
>      MySql.Data.MySqlClient.<>c.<.cctor>b__2_7(MySqlConnectionStringBuilder msb, MySqlConnectionStringOption sender) +16
>      MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnectionStringBuilder.get_Item(String keyword) +28
>      MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnectionStringBuilder.GetConnectionString(Boolean includePass) +298
>      MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection.get_ConnectionString() +41
>      System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.DbConnectionDispatcher.b__12(DbConnection t, DbConnectionInterceptionContext`1 c) +10
>      System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.InternalDispatcher`1.Dispatch(TTarget target, Func`3 operation, TInterceptionContext interceptionContext, Action`3 executing, Action`3 executed) +72
>      System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.DbConnectionDispatcher.GetConnectionString(DbConnection connection, DbInterceptionContext interceptionContext) +361
>      System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalConnection.GetStoreConnectionString(DbConnection connection) +159
>      System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalConnection.OnConnectionInitialized() +28
>      System.Data.Entity.Internal.EagerInternalConnection..ctor(DbContext context, DbConnection existingConnection, Boolean connectionOwned) +70
>      System.Data.Entity.DbContext..ctor(DbConnection existingConnection, Boolean contextOwnsConnection) +55
>      System.Data.Entity.Migrations.History.HistoryContext..ctor(DbConnection existingConnection, String defaultSchema) +16
>      MySql.Data.Entity.<>c.<.ctor>b__0_1(DbConnection existingConnection, String defaultSchema) +29
>      System.Data.Entity.Migrations.History.HistoryRepository.CreateContext(DbConnection connection, String schema) +37
>      System.Data.Entity.Migrations.History.d__16.MoveNext() +737
>      System.Linq.Enumerable.Any(IEnumerable`1 source) +77
>      System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.UpdateInternal(String targetMigration) +58
>      System.Data.Entity.Migrations.<>c__DisplayClasse.b__d() +13
>      System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.EnsureDatabaseExists(Action mustSucceedToKeepDatabase) +422
>      System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.Update(String targetMigration) +78
>      System.Data.Entity.MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion`2.InitializeDatabase(TContext context) +108
>      System.Data.Entity.Internal.<>c__DisplayClassf`1.b__e() +76
>      System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.PerformInitializationAction(Action action) +60
>      System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.PerformDatabaseInitialization() +357
>      System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.b__4(InternalContext c) +7
>      System.Data.Entity.Internal.RetryAction`1.PerformAction(TInput input) +110
>      System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.InitializeDatabaseAction(Action`1 action) +198
>      System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.InitializeDatabase() +73
>      System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.Initialize() +30
>      System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.GetEntitySetAndBaseTypeForType(Type entityType) +16
>      System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.Initialize() +53
>      System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.GetEnumerator() +15
>      System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbQuery`1.System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable.GetEnumerator() +53
>      System.Collections.Generic.List`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 collection) +375
>      System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList(IEnumerable`1 source) +54
>      ProtoSim.Controllers.SoftwareController.Index() in D:\Visual Studio\Projects\Website Projects\ProtoSim\ProtoSim\Controllers\SoftwareController.cs:13
>      lambda_method(Closure , ControllerBase , Object[] ) +61
>      System.Web.Mvc.ActionMethodDispatcher.Execute(ControllerBase controller, Object[] parameters) +14
>      System.Web.Mvc.ReflectedActionDescriptor.Execute(ControllerContext controllerContext, IDictionary`2 parameters) +157
>      System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethod(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, IDictionary`2 parameters) +27
>      System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c.b__9_0(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ActionInvocation innerInvokeState) +22
>      System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`2.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +29
>      System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +49
>      System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeActionMethod(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +32
>      System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncInvocationWithFilters.b__11_0() +50
>      System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass11_1.b__2() +228
>      System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass7_0.b__1(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +10
>      System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +10
>      System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +49
>      System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeActionMethodWithFilters(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +34
>      System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass3_6.b__3() +35
>      System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass3_1.b__5(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +100
>      System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +10
>      System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +49
>      System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeAction(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +27
>      System.Web.Mvc.<>c.b__152_1(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ExecuteCoreState innerState) +11
>      System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +29
>      System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +49
>      System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecuteCore(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +45
>      System.Web.Mvc.<>c.b__151_2(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Controller controller) +13
>      System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +22
>      System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +49
>      System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +26
>      System.Web.Mvc.Controller.System.Web.Mvc.Async.IAsyncController.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +10
>      System.Web.Mvc.<>c.b__20_1(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ProcessRequestState innerState) +28
>      System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +29
>      System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +49
>      System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +28
>      System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.System.Web.IHttpAsyncHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult result) +9
>      System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +576
>      System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStepImpl(IExecutionStep step) +132
>      System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +163

Comment: First question...are you able to connect from you computer, to you database server using `mysql` console or via GUI, like https://www.heidisql.com/

Comment: Yes, I can open it with Heidisql and can see everything that's there

Comment: Why do you have the remove DBName as well as the add in the connectionStrings section of you web.config?

Comment: Just a hunch...try deleting `integrated security=True` from your `connectionString`.

Comment: @BenOotjers
It removes the name just in case it already exists

Comment: @Hackerman
Removing "integrated security=True" does not solve the problem, rather causes another

Comment: I was looking at this Q&A https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40950988/ef6-with-mysql-the-given-key-was-not-present-in-the-dictionary

Comment: Removing that gives a new error: "Unable to update database to match the current model because there are pending changes and automatic migration is disabled". This is wrong, though, as my database IS up-to-date