# Create edmx with MySQL "The given key was not present in the dictionary"

Tags: c#, mysql, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api, edmx

I try to create a new c# web API project, and I want to connect it by edmx to MySQL.
I made a new connection, fill Server, username, password and choose the database. Finally, I test the connection it popup a "successful".

when I click OK it gives this message "The given key was not present in the dictionary"

However, I installed before that the MySQL connector to VisualStudio.
[image: This is the Popup]

Comment: this may be the collation & character set problem. Please [look here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41930040/net-mysql-error-the-given-key-was-not-present-in-the-dictionary)

Comment: It didn't solve my problem, the popup still occurred.

Answer (score 0):

Your connection string looks wrong on the screenshot, I can only see some part of it, but it looks different from what you can see in the mySql docs: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/connector-net-tutorials-entity-framework-winform-data-source.html

They haves similar issue here: [EF6 with MySQL. The given key was not present in the dictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40950988/ef6-with-mysql-the-given-key-was-not-present-in-the-dictionary) and it says that you should have properties in your connection string like: server, user id, password, database, but as I can see you have something different.

Comment: This connection string on the screenshot is for a previous Connection, but when I have finished filling (Server, username, and password) in the new connection and click "Ok", it automatically exits the connection Properties and gives this popup.

Comment: On their problem they made an update for the connection, But, I am creating a new connection.

Comment: Do you use the "MySQL Database (MySQL Data Provider)" as data source when you create the new connection? Do you have the latest MySQL for Visual Studio installed on your machine?: https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/windows/visualstudio/ just tested the same with mysql 8.0.15 and Visual Studio 2017, and I can't reproduce this.

Comment: I am using MySQL database as a data source, and I checked the connector, but the problem still.